# Преобразовать список кортежей в список списков

Tags: python, list, список, tuple

сверху мой вывод. снизу правильный, каким образом я могу изменить список в массив?
[image: результат]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то так:

```
arr = [(0,0,0),(0,0,1)]
new_arr = []
for l in arr:
    new_arr.append(list(l))
print(new_arr)

#результат: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list_of_tuples = [(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,1)]
my_list_of_lists = list(map(list, my_list_of_tuples))
```

Comment: спасибо, изучу "map"